# How to draw a clipped & curved 2D arrow in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

I just made the following figure:

[image]

Using the following code:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}

 \makeatletter
 \pgfdeclareradialshading[tikz@ball]{ball}{\pgfqpoint{-10bp}{10bp}}{%
   color(0bp)=(gray!20); 
   color(9bp)=(gray!30);
   color(18bp)=(gray!50); 
   color(25bp)=(gray!50); 
   color(50bp)=(gray)}
 \makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[-stealth,color=gray!30!black,very thick] (1,-0.6) -- (1,0.65);
\filldraw[color=black, fill opacity=0,thick](1,0) circle (0.4);
 \shade [ball color=white] (1,0) circle (0.4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

I would like to make an arrow that looks like the red arrow below:

[image]

Comment: There's a post somewhere about this kind of arrow, I think, with answers. But my search skills are failing me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an example for the first part of the arrow:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt, multi]{standalone}
\pgfdeclareradialshading[myballcolour]{my ball}{\pgfpoint{-10bp}{10bp}}{%
  color(0bp)=(myballcolour!20);
  color(9bp)=(myballcolour!30);
  color(18bp)=(myballcolour!50);
  color(25bp)=(myballcolour!50);
  color(50bp)=(myballcolour)}
\tikzset{%
  my ball colour/.code={%
      \colorlet{myballcolour}{#1}
  },
  my ball/.style={%
    my ball colour=#1,
    shading=my ball,
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [-stealth, color=gray!30!black, very thick] (1,-0.6) -- (1,0.65);
  \node (n) [my ball=yellow, circle, thick, draw=gray!30!black, minimum size=23.5bp] at (1,0) {};
  \draw [fill=red] (n.160) ++(175:1.5pt)  .. controls +(-.15,-.025) and  +(-.35,0) ..  ([yshift=-1.5pt,xshift=-5pt]n.center) -- ++(0,1pt) -- ++(2.5pt,-1.5pt) -- ++(-2.5pt,-1.5pt) -- ++(0,1pt) .. controls +(-.35,0) and +(-.15,-.025) ..  cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: something]

To ensure the other part matches, you might draw the entire curve and clip it appropriately. For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt, multi]{standalone}
\pgfdeclareradialshading[myballcolour]{my ball}{\pgfpoint{-10bp}{10bp}}{%
  color(0bp)=(myballcolour!20);
  color(9bp)=(myballcolour!30);
  color(18bp)=(myballcolour!50);
  color(25bp)=(myballcolour!50);
  color(50bp)=(myballcolour)}
\tikzset{%
  my ball colour/.code={%
      \colorlet{myballcolour}{#1}
  },
  my ball/.style={%
    my ball colour=#1,
    shading=my ball,
  }
}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [-stealth, color=gray!30!black, very thick] (1,-0.6) -- (1,0.65);
  \node (n) [my ball=yellow, circle, thick, draw=gray!30!black, minimum size=23.5bp] at (1,0) {};
  \draw [fill=red] (n.160) ++(175:1.5pt)  .. controls +(-.15,-.025) and  +(-.5,0) ..  ([yshift=-2.5pt,xshift=-1.5pt]n.center) -- ++(0,1pt) -- ++(3pt,-1.5pt) -- ++(-3pt,-1.5pt) -- ++(0,1pt) .. controls +(-.5,0) and +(-.15,-.025) ..  cycle ;
  \begin{scope}
    \clip ([xshift=3pt]n.center) |- ($(n.20)+(5:5pt)$) -- ($(n.-20)+(5:5pt)$) -| cycle;
    \draw [fill=red] (n.160) ++(175:1.5pt)  .. controls +(-.15,-.025) and  +(-.5,0) ..  ([yshift=-2.5pt,xshift=-1.5pt]n.center) -- ++(3pt,0) .. controls +(.5,0) and +(.15,-.025) .. ($(n.20)+(5:1.5pt)$) .. controls +(.15,-.025) and +(.5,0) .. ([yshift=-3.5pt,xshift=1.5pt]n.center) -- ++(-3pt,0) .. controls +(-.5,0) and +(-.15,-.025) ..  cycle ;
  \end{scope}
  \draw ([yshift=-2.5pt,xshift=3pt]n.center)  ++(0,.5pt) ++(.5\pgflinewidth,-\pgflinewidth) -- ++(0,-1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: match arrow parts]

## EDIT

Here's a way of producing the version asked for in comments which reverses the arrow. It also turns the picture into a `pic` with configurable colours and (to some extent) size. The syntax is

```
atom
```

for the defaults or

```
atom={<options>}
```

otherwise. Available options are

```
colour=<atom's colour>
orbit=<orbital arrow's colour>
size=<size of atom>
reverse=true|false
```

`reverse` without a value will set `reverse=true`. Then we can write

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic {atom};
  \begin{scope}[xshift=40bp]
    \pic {atom={colour=blue, orbit=magenta, reverse}};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

to produce

[image: opposed orbital spins]

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt, multi]{standalone}
\pgfdeclareradialshading[myballcolour]{my ball}{\pgfpoint{-10bp}{10bp}}{%
  color(0bp)=(myballcolour!20);
  color(9bp)=(myballcolour!30);
  color(18bp)=(myballcolour!50);
  color(25bp)=(myballcolour!50);
  color(50bp)=(myballcolour)}
\newif\iforbitreverse
\tikzset{%
  my ball colour/.code={%
      \colorlet{myballcolour}{#1}
  },
  my ball/.style={%
    my ball colour=#1,
    shading=my ball,
  },
  pics/atom/.style={%
    code={%
      \tikzset{%
        atom/.cd,
        #1
      }
      \draw [-stealth, color=gray!30!black, very thick] (0,-.725*\atomsize) -- (0,.79*\atomsize);
      \node (n) [my ball=\atomcol, circle, thick, draw=gray!30!black, minimum size=\atomsize] at (0,0) {};
      \iforbitreverse
        \draw [fill=\orbitcol] (n.20) ++(35:1.5pt)  .. controls +(.15,-.025) and  +(.5,0) ..  ([yshift=-2.5pt,xshift=1.5pt]n.center) -- ++(0,1pt) -- ++(-3pt,-1.5pt) -- ++(3pt,-1.5pt) -- ++(0,1pt) .. controls +(.5,0) and +(.15,-.025) ..  cycle ;
        \begin{scope}
          \clip ([xshift=-3pt]n.center) |- ($(n.160)+(175:5pt)$) -- ($(n.-160)+(175:5pt)$) -| cycle;
          \draw [fill=\orbitcol] (n.20) ++(35:1.5pt)  .. controls +(.15,-.025) and  +(.5,0) ..  ([yshift=-2.5pt,xshift=1.5pt]n.center) -- ++(-3pt,0) .. controls +(-.5,0) and +(-.15,-.025) .. ($(n.160)+(175:1.5pt)$) .. controls +(-.15,-.025) and +(-.5,0) .. ([yshift=-3.5pt,xshift=-1.5pt]n.center) -- ++(3pt,0) .. controls +(.5,0) and +(.15,-.025) ..  cycle ;
        \end{scope}
        \draw ([yshift=-2.5pt,xshift=-3pt]n.center)  ++(0,.5pt) ++(-.5\pgflinewidth,-\pgflinewidth) -- ++(0,-1pt);
      \else
        \draw [fill=\orbitcol] (n.160) ++(175:1.5pt)  .. controls +(-.15,-.025) and  +(-.5,0) ..  ([yshift=-2.5pt,xshift=-1.5pt]n.center) -- ++(0,1pt) -- ++(3pt,-1.5pt) -- ++(-3pt,-1.5pt) -- ++(0,1pt) .. controls +(-.5,0) and +(-.15,-.025) ..  cycle ;
        \begin{scope}
          \clip ([xshift=3pt]n.center) |- ($(n.20)+(5:5pt)$) -- ($(n.-20)+(5:5pt)$) -| cycle;
          \draw [fill=\orbitcol] (n.160) ++(175:1.5pt)  .. controls +(-.15,-.025) and  +(-.5,0) ..  ([yshift=-2.5pt,xshift=-1.5pt]n.center) -- ++(3pt,0) .. controls +(.5,0) and +(.15,-.025) .. ($(n.20)+(5:1.5pt)$) .. controls +(.15,-.025) and +(.5,0) .. ([yshift=-3.5pt,xshift=1.5pt]n.center) -- ++(-3pt,0) .. controls +(-.5,0) and +(-.15,-.025) ..  cycle ;
        \end{scope}
        \draw ([yshift=-2.5pt,xshift=3pt]n.center)  ++(0,.5pt) ++(.5\pgflinewidth,-\pgflinewidth) -- ++(0,-1pt);
      \fi
    }
  },
  atom/.search also={/tikz},
  atom/.cd,
  colour/.store in=\atomcol,
  size/.store in=\atomsize,
  orbit/.store in=\orbitcol,
  reverse/.is if=orbitreverse,
  colour=yellow,
  size=23.5bp,
  orbit=red,
  reverse=false,
}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic {atom};
  \begin{scope}[xshift=40bp]
    \pic {atom={colour=blue, orbit=magenta, reverse}};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is just beautiful, thanks! :). I tried to play with the code to EXACTLY reverse the arrow (I need to make two sphere spinning oppositely). But I am not getting very good results. Even using "rotate" gives bad results.

Comment: @Mike Please see edit above.